# Cart Items Total to include qty of variants

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

By using `line total: {{ cart.lineItems|length }}` it returns the number of 'products' in the current sessions cart. However, this doesn't seem to take into account the qty of each variant.

So if I add 3 of variant A and 2 of variant B, the lineItems|length would equal 2. But I want to cart to show there are 5 items added.

How can I get the total of all the items in the cart including qty of each variant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the total quantity of items with:

`cart.totalQty`

Docs: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model#totalqty

Answer (score 1):

After working on this for a while and the help of a fellow developer. The following solution seems to work. Unless anyone can improve on it?

```
{% set cartQty = 0 %}
{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
    {% set cartQty = cartQty + item.qty %}
{% endfor %}
```